# NHibernate profiler doesnt fetch my sessions

Tags: nhibernate

I've just downloaded nhibernate profiler and I cannot figure why it is not working. 
As far as I know, it should be enough to set Connection string inside Options - Edit default connection.

I'm using sql server and I've copied my connection string like this

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_xxx_MyDb;Integrated Security=True;
```

In debug mode of my app I have nothing inside nhibernate profiler when executing my app.

**Update:**
Added reference to my mvc3 project

```
HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   #if DEBUG
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
   #endif
}
```

I made following steps

1. start NhProf.exe
2. start debugging mvc app, these app queries I want to profile

Nothing appears in Nhibernate profiler. Licence is working for 32 days. 
Why? What else should I do?

**Second update:**
I tried with reference `HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll` still no working.
Tried with options-settings-listen port to set my asp dev. server port, right now is 5442. 
Still nothing. I'm bit confused.

Just to mention that my app works, my connection string works, I am able to fetch data from my db, ...

My log.txt file inside NHProfiler folder have this content

```
2012-03-28 20:31:01,374 [1] INFO  Rhino.Licensing.LicenseValidator [(null)] - License expiration date is 04/29/2012 00:00:00
2012-03-28 20:31:01,662 [1] DEBUG Rhino.Licensing.LicenseValidator [(null)] - License accepted for NHibernate Profiler
2012-03-28 20:31:02,461 [6] INFO  HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Client.App [(null)] - Checking for updates...
2012-03-28 20:31:25,072 [4] ERROR HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Client.App [(null)] - Error while checking for updates: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 216.121.112.229:80
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at NAppUpdate.Framework.Sources.SimpleWebSource.GetUpdatesFeed()
   at NAppUpdate.Framework.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdates(IUpdateSource source, Action`1 callback)
   at NAppUpdate.Framework.UpdateManager.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CheckForUpdateAsync>b__1()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you initialized the NHibernateProfiler in your app/websites?

Something like this in the Applicattion_Start() or Main()

```
#if DEBUG
  HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
#endif
```

Also remember to reference the dll

```
HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll
```

Comment: ofcourse not :) Im using mvc3 it should be inside  Application_Start() in global.asax. I'll give it try

Comment: no luck. I'm added HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.v4.0.dll
 and inside Application_Start() #if DEBUG
  HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
#endif

Do I need to modify web.config

Comment: no edit to the web.config. Maybe a stupid question, but are you testing in release mode?. because what I wrote works only if in debug mode due to the "if DEBUG" condition.

Comment: As other trial, try using HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll instead of the 4.0 one. as stated in their [Getting started](http://www.nhprof.com/Learn/GettingStarted)

Comment: @Irido still nothing. I tried with these HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll instead of the 4.0 ver. Updated question again. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

After returning default listening port inside options-settings everything works. Finally. Thanks @Iridio.

Btw if anyone needs to conclude:

Step 1: Add reference

Step 2: Inside Global.asax Application_Start() add these line

```
#if DEBUG
            HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
#endif
```

Step 3: Start NhProf, inside Options-Connection string add your conn.string.

Step 4: Run your app.

The default listening port is 22897. Do not change this.